# How can I manipulate my data to compute a mean in R with multiple NA instances?

Tags: r, mean

I am using R studio and have an extremely large dataset which has 4 variables. I am trying to compute a mean for the hours between 06:30:00 and 19:00:00 of the O2 column for every day. A sample of the dataset looks like:

```
RBWQ <- read.csv(".../R/WY06 to WY19.csv", skip = 2, header = TRUE, sep = ",", na.strings=c("","NA"))
RBWQ <- setNames(RBWQ, c("datetime","NDCQ","O2","SpCond","PaseoQ"))
```

```
View(RBWQ)

    datetime              NDCQ O2   SpCond PaseoQ
1   2005-10-01 00:00:00   NA   NA   NA     827
2   2005-10-01 00:15:00   NA   NA   NA     857
3   2005-10-01 00:30:00   NA   NA   NA     857
4   2005-10-01 00:45:00   NA   NA   NA     807
5   2005-10-01 01:00:00   NA   10   300    797
6   2005-10-01 01:15:00   NA   10.3 319    817
7   2005-10-01 01:30:00   NA   10   401    797
8   2005-10-01 01:45:00   NA   10.2 398    788
9   2005-10-01 02:00:00   NA   NA   NA     788
10  2005-10-01 02:15:00   NA   NA   NA     807
```

There are 15 minute intervals for each hour and as you can see there are a lot of NA's in this dataset. How can I manipulate this dataset determine the mean during that specific portion of time for each day and have it generate a report in a table with the day and mean in R?

```
dput(head(RBWQ))

    structure(list(datetime = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), min = c(0L, 15L, 30L, 45L, 0L, 15L), hour = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), mday = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), mon = c(9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), year = c(105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L
), wday = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), yday = c(273L, 273L, 273L, 
273L, 273L, 273L), isdst = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), zone = c("MDT", 
"MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), class = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt")), NDCQ = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), O2 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), SpCond = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), PaseoQ = c(827L, 857L, 857L, 807L, 
797L, 817L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Some days may have NA for the entire day when the instrument was not properly reading due to various reasons such a being buried.

```
dput(head(RBWQ, 96))
    structure(list(datetime = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 15L, 30L, 45L, 0L, 15L, 
    30L, 45L, 0L, 15L, 30L, 45L, 0L, 15L, 30L, 45L, 0L, 15L, 30L, 
    45L, 0L, 15L, 30L, 45L, 0L, 15L, 30L, 45L, 0L, 15L, 30L, 45L, 
    0L, 15L, 30L, 45L, 0L, 15L, 30L, 45L, 0L, 15L, 30L, 45L, 0L, 
    15L, 30L, 45L, 0L, 15L, 30L, 45L, 0L, 15L, 30L, 45L, 0L, 15L, 
    30L, 45L, 0L, 15L, 30L, 45L, 0L, 15L, 30L, 45L, 0L, 15L, 30L, 
    45L, 0L, 15L, 30L, 45L, 0L, 15L, 30L, 45L, 0L, 15L, 30L, 45L, 
    0L, 15L, 30L, 45L, 0L, 15L, 30L, 45L, 0L, 15L, 30L, 45L), hour = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
    15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 
    21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L), mday = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
        mon = c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
        9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
        9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
        9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
        9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
        9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
        9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), year = c(105L, 105L, 105L, 
        105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 
        105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 
        105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 
        105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 
        105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 
        105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 
        105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 
        105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 
        105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 
        105L, 105L, 105L), wday = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
        6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
        6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
        6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
        6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
        6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
        6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), yday = c(273L, 
        273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 
        273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 
        273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 
        273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 
        273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 
        273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 
        273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 
        273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 
        273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 
        273L, 273L, 273L, 273L, 273L), isdst = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L), zone = c("MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", 
        "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", 
        "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", 
        "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", 
        "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", 
        "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", 
        "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", 
        "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", 
        "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", 
        "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", 
        "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT", "MDT"
        ), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"
    )), NDCQ = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), O2 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
        SpCond = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_), PaseoQ = c(827L, 857L, 857L, 807L, 797L, 817L, 
        797L, 788L, 788L, 807L, 788L, 797L, 807L, 797L, 778L, 797L, 
        807L, 797L, 750L, 741L, 750L, 714L, 714L, 696L, 696L, 687L, 
        687L, 678L, 678L, 661L, 669L, 661L, 678L, 678L, 696L, 661L, 
        644L, 635L, 661L, 644L, 644L, 635L, 635L, 627L, 635L, 652L, 
        652L, 652L, 644L, 635L, 644L, 652L, 661L, 652L, 661L, 635L, 
        661L, 644L, 652L, 635L, 644L, 619L, 619L, 619L, 635L, 635L, 
        635L, 652L, 635L, 652L, 652L, 661L, 652L, 652L, 652L, 652L, 
        661L, 652L, 644L, 627L, 619L, 635L, 619L, 619L, 603L, 611L, 
        603L, 603L, 619L, 635L, 635L, 635L, 627L, 619L, 635L, 619L
        )), row.names = c(NA, 96L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you for the welcome! I appreciate it and any help you can provide. Is there a good way to add 96 rows of data so I can upload a full day? Should I  just copy paste that in my question?

Comment: You could just edit it into your question after obtaining the code from `dput` as @Ben suggested. Alternatively you could upload it to GitHub or PasteBin and edit a link into your question.

Comment: It starts on this line "NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_ ), O2 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_," for O2

Comment: Yes, but every single value is `NA_real_`. I'll answer your question with simulated data and hope it works for you.

Comment: Hey Ian, here is the link from PasteBin https://pastebin.com/Zeh4u5Cq

Comment: How could you calculate a mean if **all** of the values are NA?

Comment: For that day yes, but the dataset contains 13 years of data in 15 minute interval data... So some days there are NA for the entire day, but the data is continuous for all 13 years. I  would like to exclude the days or simply put NA for days where the entire day is NA or produce a 0, it doesn't matter as long as it's consistent.

Answer (score 0):

For time series data, consider `xts` package. Create a time series based on your data (with your datetime in first column). Then subset based on time frame, and use `colMeans` to calculate daily means (removing `NA`). Please let me know if this is what you had in mind.

```
library(xts)

RBWQ_xts <- xts(RBWQ[, -1], RBWQ[, 1])

apply.daily(RBWQ_xts["T06:30:00/T19:00:00"], colMeans, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: I  really appreciate your help. I  am getting the following error: Error in xts(RBWQ[, -1], RBWQ[, 1]) : 
  'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf'        So I'm not able to determine if that's what I was looking for yet. Do you know how I overcome that error?

Comment: @Eddie You might have `NA` as a datetime in your data? If so, then `xts` will give an error. Instead of trying to perform this on all of your data, maybe try to subset a few days where you have data, and see if this gives you what you want?

Comment: OK I will do that and see if I can run a test to determine if there is an NA in the datetime. There shouldn't be...

Answer (score 0):

Since there are so many rows, I recommend a `data.table` approach.

First, we assign new columns `date` and `time` so that we can easily filter them in the next step. We can use the optimized `data.table` functions `as.IDate` and `as.ITime` so that calculation can occur quickly.

Next, we filter on your times of interest.

We calculate mean with base R's `mean` function, and use the argument `na.rm = TRUE`.

Lastly, we group `by = date` so that the means are calculated and returned for each day.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(RBWQ)[,`:=`(date = as.IDate(datetime),time = as.ITime(datetime))][
  time > as.ITime("06:30:00") & time < as.ITime("19:00:00"),
  .(meanO2 = mean(O2,na.rm=TRUE)),
  by = date]
#         date    meanO2
#1: 2005-10-01 10.210526
#2: 2005-10-02  9.910526
```

I suspect that the calculation on the approximately 450000 rows can be done in a few seconds.

Comment: I agree that `data.table` makes good sense with the amount of data you have.

Comment: I  received the following error: Error in min * 60L : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Try `setDT(RBWQ)[,datetime := as.POSIXct(datetime)]` and then try the code in the answer again.

Comment: I  received the same error. I really appreciate both of you taking the time to help me.